# reduceByKey() dict not working as intended

Tags: dictionary, mapreduce, apache-spark, nonetype, pyspark

I have a function wherein I read in data from a text file and plan to create a dictionary of all the values per key. I have the following code snippet to achieve this:

```
def concat_helper(a,b):
    if(a!= None and b!=None):
        print a,b,a.update(b)
        return dict(a).update(dict(b))
    elif a!=None:
        return a
    elif b!=None:
        return b

rdd_text=sc.textFile(inputdir)
new_rdd = rdd_text.map(lambda x: (item_id_to_idx[str(x.strip().split("\t")[0])],{user_id_to_idx[str(x.strip().split("\t")[1])]:1})).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: concat_helper(x,y)).sortByKey()
```

`rdd_text` file is an rdd of input lines of the form:

```
item_id      user_id     some other tab_separated fields.
```

item_id_to_idx and user_id_to_idx both are dictionaries with user id to idx (an integer number) mapping.

I want to ultimately create a per item dictionary of the form:

1,{5:1,10:1,34:1,...}   where the indices to the left of the colon inside the dict (keys) represent user_indices and the numbers to the right of the colon represent their scores.

I am trying to reduceByKey but am getting a lot of None values.

The helper function I have was created to overcome a NoneType issue that reduceByKey was throwing.

The output I am receiving is of the form:

```
(item_idx, {user_idx:1})
(item_idx2,None)
(item_idx3,None) 
...
```

I suspect the None values are a result of the a.update(b) operation in the `concat_helper` method. Could anyone clarify what is happening / suggest a better more correct way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the line:

```
return dict(a).update(dict(b))
```

dict.update *always* returns None - it is useful for its side effects alone.

You should use instead:

```
a.update(b)
return a
```

You probably want empty dictionaries as the output if both a and b are None:

```
def concat_helper(a, b):
    rval = a or {}
    rval.update(b or {})
    return rval
```